# I have a angularjs table populated using ng-repeat from a JSON obj. How do I show the table rows with different colors based on a column value?

Tags: angularjs

My code is something like below..

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in employee">
    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.company }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Name Age Company

John 25 Apple

Jim   26  Apple

Joe   27  Microsoft

Sam   28  Microsoft

Now I want the first 2 rows to be displayed in a color say red and the last 2 rows to be displayed in another color say blue based on the company name. I want to do this without hard coding the company name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngClass` directive like:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in employee" ng-class="{{x.company | lowercase}}">
  <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.company }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then define those classes in your CSS:

```
.apple{
  background-color:red;
}
.microsoft{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering..Like I said I want to do it without hard coding the company value (in CSS or anywhere in the code) as I have a number of different values for company and that keeps changing. So a generic code that changes color for different company name would be great.

Comment: @Ben well anyhow you need to define what color a company name should get somewhere, like a map or an array. Otherwise there should be specific logic to decide the color for a company which is not mentioned in question. In any case, you can add that logic in a filter or a controller method and return generic CSS class like `red`, `blue`.  `ng-class="{{x.company | customFilter}}"` or `ng-class="{{someMethodInScope(x.company)}}"`